# Virtual network virbr0 cannot connect to internet anymore

Tags: firewall, libvirt, firewalld, virt-manager

I have VMs in virt-manager. Normally, they can connect to the internet. These VMs are connected to my default virtual network, device `virbr0`.  To reach the internet, the virtual network is configured as "NAT forwarding".

But the VMs can no longer connect to the internet.  They can `ping` the host, on the IP address 192.168.122.1, which the VMs see as their default router.  However, `ping google.com` hangs for 5 seconds and then returns `No address associated with hostname`.

I thought this might be a problem with the host firewall.  I tried `systemctl stop firewalld`, and now `sudo iptables-save` shows as empty, but the VMs still cannot connect to the internet.  Strangely, `ping google.com` now is able to resolve an IP address, but does not show any ping replies, nor any ICMP errors.  I.e.:

```
PING google.com (216.58.198.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
44 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 44018ms
```

What could have gone wrong? How can I find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now `sudo iptables-save` shows as empty, but the VMs still cannot connect to the internet.

The NAT forwarding on the virtual network uses `iptables` rules.  Therefore if the iptables rules are empty, it cannot work :-).

The problem happened because I had already stopped and started `firewalld`, to diagnose a different issue.  This wiped out the necessary `iptables` rules.

To reset the virtual network, re-creating the necessary `iptables` rules, run `systemctl restart libvirtd`.